# Migrate to Amazon SQL Server RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have been attempting to move from a regular SQL Server on a Win2008 Server to the SQL Server on Amazon AWS RDS.

I thought an simple backup and restore would work. Though AWS RDS doesn't seem to have access to a file system so the sql scripts all seem to need a local file system on the source and destination server. I attempted a script following

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server='test.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'

-- Verify that the servers were linked (lists linked servers)
exec sp_linkedservers

EXEC ('RESTORE DATABASE [orchard] FROM DISK = ''C:\Temp\orchard.bak'' WITH FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10')
AT [test.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com]
```

Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Are you just transfering database schema or do you need to transfer data as well?

Comment: The fact that it's Amazon RDS doesn't factor into this. You have to remember that any time you access a local file system, it's with respect to the database engine that's running the T-SQL. In this case, you're trying to restore a file from the Amazon instance's C drive. That file doesn't exist there. If possible, get your file up there somehow or onto a server where you can access it via UNC. However, I wouldn't be surprised if this is not possible with RDS.

Answer (score 51):

download the free 'SQL Azure Migration Wizard' from [CodePlex](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) -- I did a short [blog/screencast](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/aws-rds-sql-server-vs-sql-azure-smackdown-importing-data/) about this.  Be sure to set the 'TO' setting in the wizard to the AWS DNS name and then use 'SQL Server 2008' and **not** 'SQL Azure'

Comment: I guess Amazon don't want to link to this on their docs but is a FAR FAR easier way to migrate than what they suggest (which I've wasted hours on hours on previously)

Comment: someone snuck in the reference at the bottom of this forum/complaint: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=442219#442219

Comment: To be clear, you're saying this tool works for moving a SQL Azure database to RDS? That doesn't seem to be the case. The source drop down only allows SQL Server and if you try to connect to the SQL Azure instance it fails.

Answer (score 8):

The official word I got for AWS support on migration of SQL databases using .bak files is that it is not supported. So no more quick restore from .bak files. They offered the official help for migration of existing databases here:

[Official AWS database migration guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html)

And the also gave me an unofficial wink at the Azure database migration tool. Just use it to generate a script of your schema and or data and execute it against your RDS instance. Its a good tool. You will have to import the .bak into a non-RDS SQL server first to do this.

[SQL Azure migration tool](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

Comment: you can now restore from a .bak file to RDS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Answer (score 7):

You will probably find that the [Data-tier Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx) BACPAC format will provide you with the most convenient solution. You can use [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213241.aspx) to produce a file that contains both the database schema and data. [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710052.aspx) will create a new database that is populated with data based on that file.

In contrast to the [Backup and Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187048.aspx) operations, Export and Import do not require access to the database server's file system.

You can work with BACPAC files using SQL Server Management Studio or via the API in .Net, Powershell, MSBuild etc.

[image: Export Data-tier Application Dialog]

Note that there are issues using this method to Export and then Import from and to Amazon RDS. As a new database is created on RDS, the following two objects are created within it.

- A User with membership in the db_owner role.
- The rds_deny_backups_trigger Trigger

[image: The rds_deny_backups_trigger Trigger]

During the import, there will be a conflict between the objects included in the BACPAC file and the ones that are added automatically by RDS. These objects are both present in the BACPAC file and automatically created by RDS as the new database is created.

If you have a non-RDS instance of SQL Server handy, then you can Import the BACPAC to that instance, drop the objects above and then export the database to create a new BACPAC file. This one will not have any conflicts when you restore it to an RDS instance.

Otherwise, it is possible to work around this issue using the following steps.

1. Edit the model.xml file within the BACPAC file (BACPACs are just zip files).
2. Remove elements with the following values in their Type attributes that are related to the objects listed above (those that are automatically added by RDS).

   - SqlRoleMembership
   - SqlPermissionStatement
   - SqlLogin
   - SqlUser
   - SqlDatabaseDdlTrigger
3. Generate a checksum for the modified version of the model.xml file using one of the ComputeHash methods on the [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x979460.aspx) class.
4. Use the [BitConverter.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) method to convert the hash to a hexadecimal string (you will need to remove the separators).
5. Replace the existing hash in the Checksum element in the origin.xml file (also contained within the BACPAC file) with the new one.
6. Create a new BACPAC file by zipping the contents of the original with both the model.xml and origin.xml files replaced with the new versions. Do NOT use [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) for this purpose as there seems to be some conflict with the zip file that is produced - the data is not included in the import. I used 7Zip without any problems.
7. Import the new BACPAC file and you should not have any conflicts with the objects that are automatically generated by RDS.

**Note:** There is another, related problem with importing a BacPac to RDS using SQL Server Management Studio which I explain [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=446092&#446092).

Answer (score 6):

I wrote up some step-by-step instructions on [how to restore a .bak file to RDS](http://www.somacon.com/p586.php) using the SQL Azure Migration Tool based on Lynn's screencast.  This is a much simpler method than the official instructions, and it worked well for several databases I migrated.

Comment: This is actually one of the best ways I've come across - it is such a very big shame that Amazon don't support proper import/export of compressed native backups. Our account manager at Amazon is well aware of this problem knows it really pisses people off - but we don't have a clear idea of if/when it will ever be supported :(

Comment: I came across your post through Googling. It worked perfectly. Surprisingly perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the export wizard in sql server management studio on your source database.  Right click on the database > tasks > export data.  There is a wizard that walks you through sending the whole database to a remote sql server.

Comment: this is a pain because the default options don't get you a working db.   you at least need to go into the SMS Tools->Options->SQL Server Object Explorer->Scripting and set "Generate scripts for dependent objects" and "Script indexes" to true before you do the export.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool designed by AWS that will answer most, if not all, of your compatibility questions - the Schema Conversion Tool for SQL Server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

Because not all sql server database objects are supported by RDS, and even varies across sql server versions, the Assessment report will be well worth your time as well:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_AssessmentReport.html

Lastly, definitely leverage Database Migration Service:
https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Answer (score 0):

The following article discussing how to Copy Database With Data – Generate T-SQL For Inserting Data From One Table to Another Table is what I needed.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/